# PHP array to jquery array via JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Im having a little confusion why the following is not working.

**get.php**

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="testing";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$name= $_GET['name'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tableone ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$array = array();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $first=mysql_result($result,$i,"firstname");
    $last=mysql_result($result,$i,"lastname");
    $date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $ID=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");

    $array[] = $first;

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

**jQuery**

```
var arr = new Array();

    $.get("get.php", function(data){
         arr = data;
         alert(arr);
    }, "json");
```

When I run the following I get a list of names that looks like this

```
["James","Lydia","John"]
```

But when I try to single out an entry such as arr[2], i am give just a 'J', why is it that the elements arnt single entries like I would expect?

Can anyone lend a hand?

Thanks!

**Update**

```
$.get("get.php", function(data){

     arr = $.parseJSON(data);
     alert(arr);
}, "json");
```

does not seem to return results?

Comment: It seems the data was not parsed to JavaScript array yet and `arr` is still a string. Otherwise, `alert(arr)` would output `James, Lydia, John`.

Comment: As a side note - `var arr = new Array();` doesn't do anything, since you'll assign another value to that variable afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`data` contains a string of the JSON, so `arr[2]` will be the third character in the string. You need to use `$.parseJSON(data)`.

Comment: So the question is why does passing the data type argument not work?

Comment: would this be how I would use it in this instance? `arr = ($.parseJSON(data));`

Comment: Yep, that's correct. No need for the wrapper, though: `arr = $.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: Hmmm, it doesnt seem to be working, would you take a look at the updated code in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP is claiming that the JSON is HTML. You need to explicitly say it is JSON to get jQuery to handle it as such automatically.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it work  nevertheless if the data type argument is provided?

Answer (score 0):

Send the json header in php via `header('Content-type: application/json');` so jQuery should automatically decode your json data.

Answer (score 0):

you can't gave the data value to the array.

```
 $.get("get.php", function(data){
     alert(data[2]);
}, "json");
```