# Taking .get json string, turn into array?

Tags: jquery, json

Im using the following to retrieve a string from php, i would like to know how to make my string into an array.

**Jquery**

```
$.get("get.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
    //alert($.parseJSON(data));
}, "json");
```

the commented out section seems to have no effect, so I cant really tell what I am doing wrong, could someone please advice?

I can post the PHP if needed.

Thanks.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="testing";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$name= $_GET['name'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tableone ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$array = array();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $first=mysql_result($result,$i,"firstname");
    $last=mysql_result($result,$i,"lastname");
    $date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $ID=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");

    $array[$i] = $first;

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Output:

`["James","Lydia","John"]`

Comment: As you have already supplied `json` as the return dataType `data` will already be an object you can use, you don't need `$.parseJSON(data)`. This is assuming your PHP page returns data in the correct format.

Comment: Please post the PHP code that generates the JSON; what you need to to is change the PHP code, not the JavaScript - `data` is whatever your PHP code returns as JSON.

Comment: `$.parseJSON` turns a string into a JSON object; you've already got a JSON object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array to jquery array via JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143361/php-array-to-jquery-array-via-json)

Comment: You do know about `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting JSON out in that callback already.  It doesn't look like it because when you "alert" it gets converted to a string that consists of a comma delimited list of the array elements.

You can see this by doing `alert(data instanceof Array);` which will spit out "true".

Comment: Ok, well I am giving php an array, how might I get `data` to be an array?

Answer (score 0):

You're already getting back something as useful than an array. Let's say your php does this:

```php
<?php echo json_encode(array('John', 'Mary', 'Joseph')); ?>
```

Inside your function where you're alerting the data, you can get access to the elements like this:

```js
alert(console.log(data[0])); //will alert "John"
alert(console.log(data[1])); //will alert "Mary"
```

If you need to loop through any of the elements, you can do so like this:

```js
$(data).each(function(index) {
    console.log(this.toString());
});​
```

Comment: thats the thing though, `alert(console.log(data[0]););` only returns a character, not a full name

Comment: Perhaps you're forgetting the array() inside the json encode?