# json string into array?

Tags: php, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taking .get json string, turn into array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143960/taking-get-json-string-turn-into-array)

Im using the following to retrieve a string from php, i would like to know how to make my string into an array.

**Jquery**

```
$.get("get.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
    //alert($.parseJSON(data));
}, "json");
```

the commented out section seems to have no effect, so I cant really tell what I am doing wrong, could someone please advice?

**PHP**

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="testing";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$name= $_GET['name'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tableone ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$array = array();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $first=mysql_result($result,$i,"firstname");
    $last=mysql_result($result,$i,"lastname");
    $date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $ID=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");

    $array[$i] = $first;

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

**Output:**

`["James","Lydia","John"]`

Comment: You already asked this question. Please edit that one rather than starting a new one.

Comment: That's the third time you basically ask the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143361/php-array-to-jquery-array-via-json Update your original question, comment on answers and wait... maybe you also have to revise some jQuery, JavaScripts basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("get.php", function(data) {
    // data is already an array => you can loop to get individual elements
    // for example
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        alert(element);
    });
});
```

Also make sure that in your PHP file you have set the proper `Content-Type` response header top `application/json`.

Comment: Isn't this just same as `$.get('get.php', function(data){}, 'json');` ?

Comment: @xdazz, absolutely the same. It's shorter.

Comment: but see that just returns me single letters, and you have `(element, index)` backwards. I would like to know how to get the different names as full objects

Comment: But they're not objects. They're strings.

Comment: ahh well then maybe my PHP is messed up, how might i get them in as string objects, instead of single characters so that i might select them?